# Limit of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

This is a super weird question coming from someone who is just starting out in mathematics.

If $n$ is a positive integer, one can notice that as $n$ grows, $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ starts to look more and more like $\mathbb{N}$. If I were a small integer $k$, the entire group would begin to look more and more indistinguishable from $\mathbb{N}$ as $n$ grows - my additive inverse is getting further and further away. Is this idea something that is studied or formalized anywhere?

Comment: In some sense this is formalized with the $p$-adics. You take a limit (of sorts) of the rings $\Bbb Z/p^n\Bbb Z$, and end up with a ring of characteristic $0$.

Comment: @ElliotG You don't have to use primes, but the results have zero divisors and as such aren't as nice.

Comment: @Arthur who said $p$ is prime? (this is 65% a joke)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be formalized to some extent in a few different ways depending on what you want to do. In [additive number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_number_theory) it's common to model problems in $\mathbb{Z}$ as problems in $\mathbb{Z}/n$ for large $n$; the idea is that e.g. if all you're doing is adding up a bounded number of bounded elements it doesn't matter which of the two you do it in, if $n$ is large enough. This can be formalized using concepts like [local groups](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/notes-on-local-groups/) or [Freiman homomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiman%27s_theorem#Freiman_homomorphisms_and_the_Ruzsa_modeling_lemma); this is not at all my area though so I don't know much more than that.

In the areas I'm more familiar with it is possible to rigorously define a particular kind of "limit" of the groups $\mathbb{Z}/n$, namely their [categorical limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)). This produces a very interesting group called the [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, which show up in various places, for example as the [absolute Galois group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Galois_group) of a [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field). These are a kind of "completion" of the integers; in particular they're uncountable, but $\mathbb{Z}$ still sits inside as a [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) subgroup.